# Preventing bootstrap dropdown from closing on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am trying to put checkboxes in a bootstrap dropdown. I do not want the dropdown to close on click but I still want it close if they click else where on the website. I still want to fire off other javascript actions on click with in the dropdown.  I have an example of the exact inverse of what I want.  This example closes the drop down on click but keeps it open when clicked from the outside the dropdown area.

```
 $(function () {
     $('.dropdown.keep-open').on({
         "shown.bs.dropdown": function() {
             $(this).data('closable', false);
         },
         "click": function() {
             $(this).data('closable', true);
         },
         "hide.bs.dropdown": function() {
             return $(this).data('closable');
         }
     });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/ZS4L7/

Answer (score 6):

I finally got it. the code is below:

```
$(function() {
    $('.dropdown.keep-open').on({
        "shown.bs.dropdown": function() {
            $(this).data('closable', false);
        },
        "click": function(event) {
            $(this).data('closable', false);
        },
        "hide.bs.dropdown": function(event) {
            temp = $(this).data('closable');
            $(this).data('closable', true);
            return temp;
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit:** Added missing semicolon on line 11.

Answer (score -1):

I had to achieve the same thing and wrote an even simpler one:

```
$('.dropdown.keep-open').one({
  'mouseenter': () => { $(this).data('closable', false); },
  'mouseleave': () => { $(this).data('closable', true); },
  'hide.bs.dropdown': () => !!$(this).data('closable')
});
```

I hope it helps someone. Btw, these are very dirty hacks, Bootstrap could really have an option for this.