# jquery - stop bootstrap dropdown from closing without stopping other events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a few dropdown menus that have buttons that produce popovers on click. When you click on the button it closes the whole dropdown menu and hides the popover, however clicking again on the button to open the dropdown shows that the popover is still open.

I have a semi-function solution that I found here: 
[Prevent Bootstrap dropdown from closing on clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639346/prevent-bootstrap-dropdown-from-closing-on-clicks), to implement:

```
 $('.dropdown li').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

but then that stops confirm boxes from appearing. 
Is there a way I can 'resume propagation' on the elements that need a confirm dialog to appear?

Comment: have u tried e.preventDefault()?

Comment: In link you provided there is no `$('.dropdown li')` but `$('.dropdown-menu')`

Comment: @Radu yes I have, same results :( 
@makshh i've tried it also with `.dropdown-menu` with the same results